# Javascript Triggering events

Tags: javascript, events, triggers

I want to trigger an event using browser API (in javascript).

Just for test I'm using right now 2 ways and work correctly :

1)

```
var event = document.createEvent( "HTMLEvents" );
event.initEvent( "dblclick", true, false );
MyElement.dispatchEvent( event );
```

2)

```
var event = new Event( 'dblclick' );
event.initEvent("dblclick",true,false);
MyElement.dispatchEvent( event );
```

But **initEvent** and **document.createEvent** are deprecated methods (by Firefox).

There is any other way to trigger events (not to create new event and not using deprecated methods)?

**Please no JQuery, pure javascript**

If possible to illustrate with a simple example will be great.

Very simple example for demostration: http://jsfiddle.net/2w308jxt/1/

In this example an click initiate also a double click ;)

Thank You.

Comment: Did you see https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener ?

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to register an event, I want to "trigger" an event already registered using Javascript:
Example initiate an registered dblclick event (or maybe drop event ) from using just click.

Comment: MDN has also article about [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) ...

Comment: Thanks Teemu,
I used **Event()** constructor to trigger events. My real application  needs **drop** event but dataTransfer cannot be "emulated" (Security risks in the drag-and-drop model) so I decided to add a new attribute to event variable (created by Event()) an check (read) them by **drop** event function.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the solution right before my eyes (Firefox only):

```
var event = new Event( 'dblclick', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true } );
MyElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Working example (Firefox only): http://jsfiddle.net/2w308jxt/2/